# IntelliJ: How to exclude files from search by name

Tags: maven, intellij-idea

I have a Maven-Project with [flatten-maven-plugin](https://www.mojohaus.org/flatten-maven-plugin/) configured. Now, when I search IntelliJ (Ctrl+Shift+F) I get lots of false positives in the generated `.flattened-pom.xml` files.

Question: How can I get rid of search-results in files named `.flattened-pom.xml`?

Comment: You can simply change the "File Mask" ... and limit that to "pom.xml" files only...

Comment: While this it true, it's quite cumbersome. I'd favour a solution that works indepedent of the file mask

Answer (score 1):

You are able to add excluded files in your Project Settings

Go to File > Project Structure

Under Project Settings there should be Modules and select the name of your module. At the bottom of the Sources tab, you can add *Excluded files*

Comment: At first it looked like a good idea. But after "Reload all Maven Projects" the setting is lost.